# How do I get a Highlighted Content carousel to automatically scroll through the content?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, modern-experience, highlighted-content-web-part, carousel

I am currently editing a SharePoint site for a client. They have a Highlighted Content web part where they display different PowerPoints containing news about the company in a carousel.

The client wants the carousel to automatically scroll through the different PowerPoints instead of manually having to press on the arrows to go further.

I have no idea how to actually do this, anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Automatic scroll is **not** supported in carousel layout of Highlighted content web part in SharePoint online.

Also, you cannot change the behavior of SharePoint out of the box web parts. So, you cannot add auto scroll functionality to out of the box web part.

---

You have to create your own web part using [SharePoint Framework (SPFx)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview).

Sample web part for reference: [Images and Videos in a Carousel](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/main/samples/react-carousel)